# Is there any way to cast splitted input() value to int when assigning splitted value to several variables?

Tags: python, input, split, casting

I want to cast splitted input to int and assign to several variables.
`x, y = input("Enter the coords:").split()`

I want to do it in the same line. Is it possible in python? `map()` and using additional lines are ok. I just want to explore possibilities of python.

I tried this: `x, y = int(input("Enter the coords:")).split()`

And got an error:
`ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10:`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension to unpack the string into integers:

```
x, y = [int(n) for n in input("Enter the coords:").split()]
```